# Using Google Forms, need script to turn form off and on daily, and to clear weekly

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I need to:

Set the form to "Not accepting responses" every weekday at 7:16 am 
Then set the form to “Accepting responses” every weekday at 5:30 am
Clear all responses from the form and the form spreadsheet on Friday at 2:00 pm

I have no experience with writing scripts. This is for a teacher sign-in sheet for a public high school.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should implement the trigger. Here is the help [article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, StackOverflow isn't here to write your code for you, so you won't receive an answer that you can copy/paste and get to work. The community will instead assist you with any specific roadblocks that you encounter with your code (If they can).

However, you'll be able to achieve this with the [Form Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getDestinationType()), specifically, the '[.setAcceptingResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setAcceptingResponses(Boolean))' method. You'll also need the [Spreadsheet service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) with the '[.clear()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear())' method to empty the sheet.

You'll find the [time triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) are the easiest way to set when the form becomes active and inactive again, however, you've mention very specific times that this needs to go offline and online again (7:16 am and 5:30 am, but only on weekdays, and 2PM to clear the sheet on Fridays), but Google Apps script time triggers can't be set down to the minute (Note the triggers explanation about the time being randomized).

An alternative would be to write a function that checks the time, have that function run every minute, and if the time = 2PM on a Friday then clear the sheet etc.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out formLimiter by New Visions Cloud Lab?
http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/add-ons/formlimiter

The description is: 
formLimiter automatically sets Google Forms to stop accepting responses after a maximum number of responses, at a specific date and time, or when a spreadsheet cell contains a specified value.

Great for time-bound assignments, event registrations with limited seats, or other first-come, first-served signup scenarios.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but formlimiter only takes a specific date and time to limit the form.  I need it to turn off and on daily at given times.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a short script and set a trigger, I named my form "Play"

[image]

Here is the script:

```
function limitDays() {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var lastDay = 21;
  var currDate = new Date();
  var dayOfMonth = currDate.getDate();
  if (dayOfMonth > lastDay) {
    form.setAcceptingResponses(false);
  } else {
    form.setAcceptingResponses(true);
  }
}
```